# get_theme_mod Not Functioning Properly

Tags: theme-customizer

The code is outputting everything (style tags, div classes, brackets, etc.) *except* the actual color that I choose.  How do I get the actual output (primary_color) to show up?

Registering the custom color picker:

```
// WP THEME CUSTOMIZER: COLORS
$colors = array();
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'primary_color', 
    'default' => '#88C34B',
    'label' => __('Primary Color', 'Ari')
);
```

Calling the color:

```
//// WP THEME CUSTOMIZER: GENERATE CSS
function mytheme_customize_css()
{
    ?>
         <style type="text/css">
             html, body, .container { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('primary_color'); ?>; }
         </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customize_css');
```

Full code can be found here:

```
//// WP THEME CUSTOMIZER: GENERATE CSS
function mytheme_customize_css()
{
    ?>
         <style type="text/css">
             html, body, .container { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('primary_color'); ?>; }
         </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customize_css');

// WP THEME CUSTOMIZER: COLORS
$colors = array();
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'primary_color', 
    'default' => '#88C34B',
    'label' => __('Primary Color', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'secondary_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Secondary Color', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'heading_bg_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Heading Background', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'heading_font_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Heading Font', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'heading_links_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Heading Links', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'heading_links_hover_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Heading Links Hover', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'headings_color', 
    'default' => '#333333',
    'label' => __('Headings Color', 'Ari')
);
$colors[] = array(
    'slug'=>'background_color', 
    'default' => '#FFFFFF',
    'label' => __('Background Color', 'Ari')
);
foreach( $colors as $color ) {
    // SETTINGS
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        $color['slug'], array(
            'default' => $color['default'],
            'type' => 'option', 
            'capability' => 
            'edit_theme_options'
        )
    );

    // CONTROLS
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            $color['slug'], 
            array('label' => $color['label'], 
            'section' => 'colors',
            'settings' => $color['slug'])
        )
    );
}

// WP THEME CUSTOMIZER: LAST LINE
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wptuts_theme_customizer', 11 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is simply this line:

```
'type' => 'option',
```

You should remove it, because the default is:

```
'type' => 'theme_mod',
```

since you want to use `get_theme_mod()`.

You should also consider:

- prefixing these color settings slugs, to make them more unique.
- using for example: `'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',` in your settings setup for sanitazion.

ps: there's some piece missing from your code snippet.

Edit by Otto: The above answer is correct. Additionally:

- When you do `get_theme_mod('primary_color')`, you should also specify the default value there, like so: `get_theme_mod('primary_color', '#88C34B')`. This will prevent it from outputting broken CSS when the user has not selected a color in the customizer yet.
- Prefixing the slugs is not actually necessary for theme-mod settings, because they are stored uniquely to the theme in any case. If you were using options and not theme-mods, then prefixing would be desirable.

Comment: @Otto - should I be declaring the default color both with get_theme_mod and in my array, or should I just be doing one of these?

Comment: Both. The default in the add_setting call is for the customizer's default. The default in the get_theme_mod call is for displaying on the site. Different defaults that should be set to the same value.